# Edit text issue in Android with Arabic Language

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a login screen that consists of two EditText views.

username  &  password fields.

When i change the language to Arabic,  the password Edit text field gets right aligned.

I dont know about RTL language rules, but i feel it is starting to work according to RTL language rules.

Username field is not effected . But password field gets right aligned.

Password Text :

```
    <EditText
android:id="@+id/login_password"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:hint="@string/login_input_password_hint" />
```

username :

```
    <EditText
android:id="@+id/login_user"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="texturi"
android:hint="@string/login_input_userid_hint" />
```

I feel the problem is with == android:inputType="textPassword"
Please tell me how to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have idea what is the reason of this issue but you can us text alignment as

```
android:gravity="left"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. but my api version of android is lower and hence i dont have Textalignment tag. I tried Gravity = left but it didnt solve my problem . as the cursor was always station on the left

Comment: is there anyway to override the RTL language and keep the input type fixed from the left side.

Comment: @Sunil Did you solve the issue with input type "textPassword"?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:gravity="right"
```

It will resolve this issues

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the location information and process accordingly.

If the location shows arabia, you can set gravity to your EditText.
Use `android:inputType="textPassword"`

And Check (Kotlin code) :

```
val locale = Locale.getDefault().language
if (locale == "ar") {
    yourEdittext.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT
} else { 
    yourEdittext.gravity = Gravity.LEFT 
}
```